# What is the equivalent of "webkit-tap-highlight-color" in Fennec?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, fennec

I want to disable the orange highlighting displayed when the user taps a link. I think iOS and Android Browsers support this by using "webkit-tap-highlight-color". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: are you talking about Outline. Try setting it zero outline:0;

Comment: Found this thread https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701690
Have you tried to add styles to :active state?

Answer (score 0):

Only `document.querySelector("a, label, button")` and change its tagName to other, for example span with appropriate aria value. You also need to change your CSS.

The tap color is hardcoded in fennec/firefox and it cannot be changed like "::selection"/::-moz-selection. Additionally ::-moz-selection is not complete, because it doesn't change image background for selected elements.

Optionally:

```
div.tap-detector
{
   position:fixed;
   height:100%;
   top:0rem;
   left:0rem;
   width:100%;
   z-index:1000;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

and redirect all click, mousemove, mousedown and mouseup events (and other if used) from div to elements under it. Redirected click shall not use tap-highlighting. Probably scroll gesture you not need to catch - elements with overflow:hidden are "transparent" for scroll gesture.

It is not clear solution and use only if YOU MUST because your boss grumbles.